# Dependent field easy admin 4

Tags: ajax, symfony, easyadmin

I have just started working with easy admin 4 and I want to get the classical dependents field, in that case, a selection in a  should field and , is something that in plain HTML + JS have no mystery form me using endpoints and ajax calls  but using the framework... I can't find a solution.

I have been reading the official documentation:
https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields/AssociationField.html
and about dependent fields in symfony as well: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/choice-type-fields.

The idea is that you are creating a Client entity that has a ManyToOne relationship with a Provider and both have a field called "percentage" the idea is that when you are creating a client and select a provider automatically the "percentage" value of the selected provider will be copied to the input "percentage" of the current client.
I guess that the easiest solution will be rendering the list of providers and inside the options add some kind of data-foo="percentage", later when selected retrieve it using JS instead of create a custom endpoint and consume it using Ajax.

I have been trying by setting a custom form and use the logic similar to the symfonycast tutorial but no luck, and by now my  closest approximation to a solution is:

1. ClientCrudController

```
    class ClientCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{


    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Client::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

        yield AssociationField::new('provider');
        yield NumberField::new('percentage');
    }
}
```

2. Override the default new @!EasyAdmin/crud/new.html.twig template to, by somehow access the provider selected value and trying to retrieve its "percentage":

```
{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/crud/new.html.twig' %}
{% block body_javascript %}
    <script>
        const providerInput = document.getElementById('Client_proveedor');
        const percentageInput = document.getElementById('Client_percentaje');
        proveedorInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
            const selectedOption = proveedorInput.options[proveedorInput.selectedIndex];
            // and now??
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

But I have no idea how to add this data-foo into the options, something like:

```
<option value=1 data-foo="3.5">provider1</option>
<option value=2 data-foo="7">provider2</option>
<option value=3 data-foo="9">provider3</option>
```

Any ideas? Suggestions, better way to do that or links to a more detailed documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry for missing details, the idea is to retrieve the current percentage value from the provider and place in input in the client entity to give the chance of sightly modify for the custom client ( it will not be always the same percent from the selected provider)

[image]

Comment: Do it on the server with a `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\BeforeEntityPersistedEvent` https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/events.html#event-subscriber-example

Comment: But if it is always to use the "live" value from the provider, modify your getter instead to get the  value from the associated provider (you don't need to save the data again).

Comment: Hi @ArleighHix, thanks for your comment, I edited my comment due to the original idea is the retrieve the original percent from the selected provider and paste in the input, leaving the user the option to modify it, it will not be always exactly the same value.

Comment: Hi @Aries finally I just gave up and move to Symfony without any framework